# Execute symfony command

Tags: php, symfony

I have a command inside my command folder under my bundle folder. I'm trying to execute it using the windows command prompt or using netbeans. The documentation says to use the bin/console. But I have no idea what is that or how to use it. Please help.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/usage.html

Comment: All I get is: Could not open input file: bin/console

Comment: php bin/console assuming you have a path set to your php executable

Comment: depends on which version of symfony you are using. If its > 3.0 than it is php bin/console otherwise it is php app/console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Symfony2, the `console` is located at /app/console

so if you `cd` to your application home directory, then run `php app/console <name of command>`

in the Command class, the name is set:

```
protected function configure()
{
    // to run the console command, use 'php app/console forex:update'
    $this->setName('forex:update')
         ->setDescription('Update Foreign Exchange Rates');
}
```

in the example above, the command to run it (from the application home directory is:

```
php app/console forex:update
```

You may also need to add the `php` to your PATH, or replace `php` with the path to your php executable.